# Как используя DatePickerDialog ввести дату раньше 1900 года?

Tags: java, android

Для ввода даты использовал `DatePickerDialog`.
Сегодня обнаружил, что даты раньше 1900 года ввести нельзя.
Можно ли это исправить и как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Инициализируем объект типа DatePickerDialog
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, 2000, 10, 10);
// Инициализируем объект типа Calendar, и устанавливаем нужный год
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1800);
// Устанавливаем это значение как минимальное для DatePickerDialog, и отображаем
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        datePickerDialog.show();
```